# adding CDATA to an XmlObject

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I am writing some code that talks to a legacy system that needs the following element:

```
<BankRate><![CDATA[        ]]><BankRate>
```

I can't for the life of me get this working, my attempt so far is:

```
parent.setBankRate("    ");
XmlCursor cursor = cc.xgetBankRate().newCursor();
cursor.toFirstContentToken();
cursor.setBookmark(CDataBookmark.CDATA_BOOKMARK);
cursor.dispose();
```

This simply results in the following:

```
<BankRate><BankRate>
```

The options for the parent is:
    setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold(0).setSaveCDataLengthThreshold(0);

If I setBankRate like the following:

```
cc.setBankRate("<![CDATA[        ]]>");
```

I get character entities (which is not what I want)

Comment: You might need to set the CDATA length threshold to a lower value since you are outputting just a few blank spaces as the text element. You can refer to the [Javadoc](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setSaveCDataLengthThreshold(int)) for guidance.

Comment: I didn't think you could go lower than **0** for cdataLengthThreshold ?

Comment: Do you have it set to zero? The default value is 32.

Comment: setSaveCDataLengthThreshold(0) and setSaveCDataEntityCountThreshold(0) are both set on the options

Comment: What is the type of the BankRate element?  Setting it may discard whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following test:

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

public class main {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws XmlException {
        XmlObject x = XmlObject.Factory.parse( "<BankRate>        </BankRate>" );
        XmlCursor c = x.newCursor();
        c.toFirstContentToken();
        c.toNextToken();
        c.setBookmark(CDataBookmark.CDATA_BOOKMARK);
        XmlOptions options = new XmlOptions();
        options.setSaveCDataLengthThreshold( 1 );
        options.setUseCDataBookmarks();
        System.out.print( x.xmlText( options ) );
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
<BankRate><![CDATA[        ]]></BankRate>
```

If your goal is to force the saving of the contents of BankRate as CDATA, this is how you do it.

However, if this does not work, and you get nothing (the empty element) as the value of BankRate, then what is probably happening is that the BankRate Type is not text, and is some other type which ignores white space.  If you really need to get whitespace as the value of BankRate, you will have to inject it with an XmlCursor.

Comment: The IDE and source both confirm that BankRate is indeed a String. WRT to your example, if you provide the options in the parse method and DON'T provide the options in the .xmlText method, you don't get CDATA.   This is my scenario in the code I am writing, its a helper method to create the nodes detail. The CDATA only appears to be applied as write time and I only want it on this certain node (and not the complete SOAP message). There is no way to force an element to include CDATA directly for single elements without going through the cursor stuff?

Comment: The setUseCDataBookmarks at the parse phase causes the parser to inject Bookmarks which indicate where CDATA was found in the source XML.  The setUseCDataBookmarks at the save phase causes CDATA to be used where ever CDATA bookmarks are found.  I am aware of only one way to cause CDATA to be used for an element, and that is to inject the CDATA bookmark using XmlCursor.  If you want to cause all other CDATA to not be used in the rest of the message, either do not specify setUseCDataBookmarks, or manually remove the bookmarks with a cursor.  Does using cursors bother you?

Comment: Your BankRate type wouldn't happen to using the normalizedString type, would it?

Comment: Thanks for your responses Eric! I have no real issue with cursors - it's just doesn't appear to be working for me at this stage. This is even after I added the extra line of code you suggested (c.toNextToken();)  If a different XmlOptions is used for parent nodes of the immediate node I am dealing with, I am thinking that this may override my cursor settings.

Comment: BankRate is a normal string type. All the setters are generated by org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java that looks at a wsdl file.

Comment: Can you include a trimmed down but complete example of your issue?  A simple schema and use of it?

Comment: HI Eric, I think the underlying issue is the axis end point class that  sends the serialized request to the outside webservice. I have placed break points at multiple points up until the axis generated code and at every point , xmlObject.xmlString(options) DOES include the CDATA. It appears that the class that extends `org.apache.axis2.client.Stub` is the culprit.  I'm going to give you the right answer as the underlying issue is NOT entirely related to the original question. If you have any suggestions with these new discoveries, I'll gladly take them!

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/Axis2-1.4-not-preserving-CDATA-td26682937.html was where I ended up finding the answer to the underlying issue

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm trying to recreate your scenario.  Here is a simple schema with an element which is of the string type.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Moo" type="xs:string">
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is a program which instantiates the type, sets the value to a few spaces and saves it.

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;
import noNamespace.*;

public class main {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws XmlException {
        MooDocument moo = MooDocument.Factory.newInstance();
        moo.setMoo( "     " );
        System.out.print( moo.xmlText() );
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
<Moo>     </Moo>
```

You can force CDATA by injecting a CDATA bookmark before the text.  In your problem, the spaces seem to be missing.  How does this differ from your problem?

Comment: Hi Eric, I missed this 2nd answer before posting a reply above. The problem is at the Axis layer (not XmlBeans)